# django retrieve data from mysql database

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django. 
I need help on retrieving data from mysql database and displaying it on the html page. 
Can someone advice please. Much appreciated! :)

Models.py:

```
class testing(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70, null=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Views.py:

```
def testing_view(request):
    test = testing.objects.get(id=1)
    return render(request, 'exampapersnew/exampaper.html', {'test': test})
```

exampapers.html:

```
      <div class="control-group">
          <div class="controls">
            <h1>{{ test }}</h1>

          </div>
      </div>
```

mySQL Database:

```
SELECT * FROM exampapersnew_testing;
+----+-----------+-------+
| id | name      | title |
+----+-----------+-------+
|  1 | Geraldine | Ms    |
+----+-----------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Well the problem here is that `test` contains *all* `testing` objects, so it is a collection, and that collection has no `.name` or `.title`. If you want to display a *single* `testing` object, you need to pass an `id`.

Comment: So the question is more, what do you want to display? One item, or *all* titems, and in case it is one item, how will you determine *which* item?

Comment: do you mean like this?
test = testing.objects.get(id='name'), testing.objects.get(id='title')

Comment: can just display 1 column item from the database table?

Comment: Nooo... Here you want to obtain *all* `testing` objects wht an `id` that is `'name'`, since most `id`s are numerical this would result in an empty *collection* (again collection).

Comment: actually i am doing a school assignment which consists of questions and answers, at the html page, i want to display the question then followed by having a 'answer' button once this button is clicked, it will show the solution for the question. But i am lost at this

Comment: in my database table, i have id, topic, subtopic, question_no, content, answer, marks

Comment: The database is of no importance here. Do you understand what the difference is between an element, and a list of elements? Right now you have a collection (let us assume that this is a list) of elements. That list can be empty, contain one item, or contain more items. So you can not obtain the attribute(s) of *elements* by querying the collection.

Comment: okay, you meant that by using testing.object.all() includes both name and title. But right now i am using .name, .title which is actually individual elements as such i will not be able to display it. Is that right?

Comment: no..... It does *always* include *all* testing objects (so all columns), but here by writing *all* you write *all rows* as well, so there are *multiple* rows in the queryset.

Comment: I really advice to first gain some experience with a database (does not have to be MySQL per se), and read the Django tutorial, I have the impression that there is some knowledge lacking here, making it virtually impossible to help you with this particular issue.

Comment: multiple rows in the queryset, do u mean that i have multiple records in my database thus .all() is calling all the records in the database?

Comment: exactly... and for *all* records, it will fetch *all* columns.

Comment: so if i use .objects.get(id=1) it will just get the first record with id=1.

Comment: no you will get *the* record if there exist such record, and otherwise get an error. Since the `id` is unique, there at most one record.

Comment: after i changed that and changed my html to just {{ test }} it still does not display the record.

Comment: Can you share your (updated) view, template, and (relevant) parts of the database?

Comment: edited as above.

Comment: Is this Python-2.x or Python-3.x?

Comment: im using python 3.6

Comment: ah, well `__unicode__` has been removed from the Python datamodel (only works in Python-2.x). so you should replace it with `__str__`.

Comment: replaced it but still couldnt display anything

Comment: The app seems to be `exampapersnew`, not `testing`, are you sure you point to the *correct* template? The template should at least display the `<div>`s.

Comment: yeah, i posted the name 'testing' instead of my actual page name, and the template .html is very long so i just paste the portion of the form. i will re-edit it

Answer (score 0):

test is not an instance of your class testing. It's a QuerySet of all the objects in your testing class. So in your html, you should use a for loop to show all the testing objects you have (doesn't matter if it's only one or many objects, you have to loop anyway).

In your html :

```
{% for t in test %}
 Name: {{ t.name }}
 Title: {{ t.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

PS :  nothing will be displayed if you didn't add objects to your Database

**EDIT 1**

You edited your question and therefore my answer has no sense anymore. In this case, I think you have a problem in your database connection.

**EDIT 2**

1/ In your console : run  python manage.py createsuperuser and fill your username and password.

2/ In you admin.py add the following :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import testing

admin.site.register(testing)
```

3/ run makemigrations and migrate again to make sure all is in place

4/ run python manage.py runserver and open your_localhost/admin, log in and you should find your model testing there and add objects to it

Comment: still got nothing displayed

Comment: The only explanation is that you have nothing in your databse. did you add objects to you testing table?

Comment: I edited my answer ! Add more information about your db connection

Comment: i used python manage.py makemigrations then followed by migrate but then i still couldnt display anything

Comment: @Gerry: migrating is not enough: migrations create tables, etc. *populating* tables is something the app is supposed to do

Comment: Cant seems to upload my template html due to the formatting.. how do i do populating tables? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: What you can do now is open your admin interface and check if your objects are there ! (if you dont have an admin account run python manage.py createsuperuser)

Comment: Check my EDIT 2 @Gerry

Comment: I can’t see my models / tables in the admin interfaces. By default it was using SQLite and I changed it to be using MySQL from then I couldn’t see anything in my admin interfaces, okay I’ll try your method @Ines Tlili

Comment: @InesTlili tried and it doesnt work still :( everythings seems ok and in the admin page i am also able to see the model testing and also able to add objects.